# Loading user classes in flink RichFilterFunction using User code classloader

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use the flink's UserCodeClassLoader but since I am new to Flink I could not understand exactly how to use it.

**Scenario:**
In the open() method of RichFilterFunction(), I want to load an external jar.

To do so, I do the following in open():

```
@Override
public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
ClassLoader userClassLoader = getRuntimeContext().getUserCodeClassLoader();
URL url = userClassLoader.getResource("/tmp/rohit/FilterTest/FilterTest.jar");
klazz = userClassLoader.loadClass("FilterTest");
Constructor<?> ctor = klazz.getConstructor();
Object obj = ctor.newInstance(new Object[] {});
control = (MyRichFilterInterface)obj;
```

... etc

However, I am getting ClassNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: FilterTest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.execution.librarycache.FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders$ChildFirstClassLoader.loadClass(FlinkUserCodeClassLoaders.java:128)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at MyRichFilterFunction.open(MyRichFilterFunction.java:24)
        at org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.util.FunctionUtils.openFunction(FunctionUtils.java:36)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractUdfStreamOperator.open(AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java:102)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.openAllOperators(StreamTask.java:393)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:254)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:718)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My flink version is 1.4.0 & it is installed in /root/flink-1.4.0/
I have not changed any parameters in flink config specific to this issue.

If anyone knows what I am missing, that would be great!!!
I have used URLClassLoader earlier, but I am not sure how to use Flink's provided UserCodeClassLoader.

Comment: How do you run flink? In some kind of cluster or in a local environment? And maybe a stupid question: Why don't you just add your FilterTest.jar to the classpath?

Comment: Why do you want to use the classloader explicitly? That's quite a complex thing, you should use only if you are really aware what's going on underneath.

Comment: Hi TobiSH - I can confirm that after adding the jar to classpath, it is working. So thanks for that. I am new to Flink/Java so I guess I missed that.

Comment: To answer why I am using classloader explicitly, I need to tell a little bit abt what I am trying to achieve. The objective is to allow real-time streaming queries on a datastream without any down time. To do so, I am connecting control & data stream and doing a coFlatMap. Output is in format Tuple2<Control, data> So if there is 3 queries and incoming data matches first two, then i will o/p two elements <control1, data1> and <control2,data1>
All operations on data (like filter, select, group & window) are encapsulated inside control (continued....)

Comment: (..continued)
For eg: for key selection, I would do something like this:
return control.getKey(data)

By explicitly using classloader, I can separate out the flink job & control object implementation. Flink job will be written with some interface & actual implementation can be left to users (Business units in this case)
so users can keep adding new implementations without worrying abt the core flink job which will remain unchanging.

I hope what I described makes sense & I was able to explain why I was looking to dynamically load classes

Comment: Maybe there is some other way / approach through which we can achieve what I just described. I would be most interested in hearing from you guys.